# How to have article URL like example.com/article1 and example.com/foo/article2?

Tags: taxonomy, urls, slug, blog

By default, blog articles have an URL like `example.com/article1`.

Changing *Settings > Permalinks* with `/%category%/%postname%/` makes it possible to have URL like:

```
example.com/foo/article2
```

Question: how to have blog articles of these 2 types:

```
example.com/article1
example.com/foo/article2
```

on the same website?

It is technically possible: multilingual websites often have this. How do they internally achieve this? (taxonomy?)

Maybe is there an easy solution to allow character `/` in the URL slug for articles?

Comment: If `article1` has no category and `article2` has the category `foo`, this should already work.

Comment: @kero With which settings in Settings > Permalinks? If I use `/%category%/%postname%/` I get `example.com/uncategorized/article1` instead of `example.com/article1`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the "uncategorized" thing .. sorry.

Comment: Use such plugin to achieve what you want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin like this to override the permalink structures on each post, post type or any other entry:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/

Comment: Thank you. Is there a solution without a plugin? And maybe just custom code in the theme's `functions.php`?

Comment: Custom codes come with complexity and may require customization for your website. I recommend using this third party plugin as it's easy to use. 

Maybe you can add an htaccess rule to override the URLs and remove the "uncategoriez" from the post slugs and it would do the trick.